# The velocity of the flowing coming out of the balloons?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Last day , when i was working on two interconnected balloons , a question was kicking my brains !!! This is the explanation of the question:

First , suppose a system that composed of two spherical membranes filled with air (two balloons have different initial volumes {means that the pressure inside which balloons are different} and the air pressure is 1 a.t.m) . We connect them with hollow tube and a valve.
When we open the valve , one of them shrinks and the other one expands (It depends on their pressure) . 
So how can we get the velocity of the flowing air between two balloons? (Consider everything but if you have reasons for not considering one of them -for example the ratio of friction in the tube- Don't consider them and just tell me the reason)

Thanks

Comment: Why the general relativity tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The air flow rate through a tube is approximately given by the [Hagen-Poiseuille](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation) equation. If the pressure difference between the two ballons is $\Delta P$ then the HP equation gives the volumetric flow rate $Q$ as:

$$ Q = \frac{\pi r^2}{8\mu \ell} \Delta P $$

where $r$ is the radius of the pipe, $\ell$ is the pipe length and $\mu$ is the viscosity of the air. The equation actually only applies to incompressible fluids, but gives [a reasonable answer even for compressible fluids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation#Poiseuille.27s_equation_for_compressible_fluids) like gases a long as the pressure differences aren't too high. In the case of two balloons it should be fine.

Comment: So ,1- Is it true if i use it for that question????
 
2- How can I get the viscosity of the air????

3- what is the relation between volumetric flow rate and velocity?

Comment: @DavidMichaele: yes.

Comment: @DavidMichaele: Google for the viscosity of air. Mass flow rate = $\rho Q$, where $\rho$ is the density of the air (about 1.25kg/m$^3$).

Comment: And = 3- what is the relation between volumetric flow rate and velocity?

Comment: @DavidMichaele: $Q = vA$ where $v$ is the (average) velocity in the tube and $A$ is the tube area.

Comment: Plugging in meters for radius and pipe length, Pascal-seconds for viscosity, and Pascals for pressure, I'm getting Q in meters per second, which doesn't line up with volumetric flow. Is there something missing?